# Setting up Taglist plugin to work with vala

Tags: ctags, vala

Like the title says,I would like to develop vala with vim.My productivity is badly affected due to the lack Taglist plugin support for vala.
I found a ctags implementation in valide, 
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~valide/valide/trunk/files/head:/ctags-vala/

Can anyone guide me how to make this ctag implemention work with Taglist or some other vim plugin which works for vala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer,
set this is .vimrc

```
let tlist_vala_settings='c#;d:macro;t:typedef;n:namespace;c:class;'.
  \ 'E:event;g:enum;s:struct;i:interface;'.
  \ 'p:properties;m:method'
```

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same needs, and I found this site :
http://sophiaongnome.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/how-do-i-set-up-my-vala-ide-in-vim/

The guy uses Tagbar in Vim, and anjuta-ctags which implement ctags for Vala.

I give you also my Vim configuration for Vala:

```
set efm=%f:%l.%c-%[%^:]%#:\ %t%[%^:]%#:\ %m
map <leader><F2> :lvimgrep! <cword> /usr/share/vala-0.16/vapi/*<CR> :lopen <CR>
set complete+=k/home/marc/.vim/syntax/vala.vim
set isk+=(
" Disable valadoc syntax highlight
"let vala_ignore_valadoc = 1

" Enable comment strings
let vala_comment_strings = 1

" Highlight space errors
let vala_space_errors = 1
" Disable trailing space errors
"let vala_no_trail_space_error = 1
" Disable space-tab-space errors
let vala_no_tab_space_error = 1

" Minimum lines used for comment syncing (default 50)
"let vala_minlines = 120

let g:tagbar_ctags_bin="anjuta-tags"
set iskeyword+=.
```

Comment: typo, it is not anjuta-ctags, it is anjuta-tags.