# How to set up Vala in the CodeBlocks?

Tags: gtk, codeblocks, vala

I'm running ElementaryOS and I want to start development in Vala (GTK+ to be specific). I have some experience with C++ , but I'm interested in the GTK+ development (I prefer it over Qt). So, is it possible?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an IDE which already has built-in Vala support (like Anjuta which is what I'm using):

There are some [IDEs that have support for Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tools):

- Geany is an integrated development environment with support for vala syntax and code completion.
- Val(a)IDE is an integrated development environment for Vala, developed with Vala. (valide is no longer supported)
- MonoDevelop comes with Vala bindings since 2.0. (monodevelop-vala is no longer supported)
- Vala Toys for gedit - Vala plugin for gedit
- Valencia - Vala plugin for gedit
- Anjuta (>= 3.0) has Vala auto-indentation, auto-completion (IntelliSense) and Glade drag&drop support for Vala. It can also manage Vala autotools projects.
- Netbeans - Plugin for the Netbeans IDE for Vala
- TextMate or RedCar - A TextMate (OS X) bundle with syntax support, snippets, and other features. It should also work with the cross-platform RedCar editor.
- Valama - An IDE with glade editor & symbols navigator

If you really want to use Code::Blocks, you probably have to go through a complicated setup process:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Adding_support_for_non_C/C%2B%2B_files_to_the_build_system

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=10383.0

Comment: Thanks, It's even better than what I could even imagine. For GTK+ projects it even has  .ui . I thought it is Qt specific.

Comment: Hi, is there any specific configuration for Anjuta to support Vala IntelliSense ? I cannot see it like in Valama for exemple.

Comment: @lighta IntelliSense is Microsoft Visual Studio technology, you mean code completion? Anjuta does that to a certain degree. Symbols are recorded when the binary is build and you can access them in a popup dialog after that.

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442936/setting-up-taglist-plugin-to-work-with-vala

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff thanks for clarification, I found out later that errors are showed after building like you said.